# How do I fix 1 unresolved externals and why is it showing up in the first place

Tags: c++, winapi, compiler-errors

I ***was*** just playing around with the message box when this error code stumbled upon me "LNK2019 unresolved external symbol_main referenced in function "int__cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)" and then right after another came up "LNK1120 unresolved externals".

I tried messing around with the precompiled Header settings, Checking all of my #include things whatever they are called and I also tried re-writing the whole thing! but nothing happened :(

```
#include <Windows.h>
int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR args,                 
int ncmdshow)
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "uwu", "This is a title belive it or not!", 
    MB_OK);




    return 0;
}
```

The expected output was a console window and then a little window that says "uwu" but instead I got an error.

Comment: Change WinMain() to main
`int main()` { ... }

Comment: The linker normally determines the executable type by the presence of a `main` or `WinMain` function.  Do you have a link option to make your program a console application (which wants `main`)?

Comment: Create a console application project in your IDE. Use `main`. See https://latedev.wordpress.com/2011/10/06/simple-windows-dialogs-from-c-part-1/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are several ways of dealing with this. The simplest and most obvious is probably to just use `main` instead of `Winmain`:

```
#include <Windows.h>
int main()
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "uwu", "This is a title believe it or not!", MB_OK);
}
```

Comment: Hmm... That doesn't seem to work. if I replace WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR args, int ncmdshow) with just WinMain() it spits out "'WinMain': function cannot be overloaded"

Comment: If I just use main it outputs the same error with the WinMain(HINSTANCE hInst, HINSTANCE hPrevInst, LPSTR args, int ncmdshow)